# trying to get the first visited date

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I am trying to do daily analysis on a particular set of data. The table looks like this:

```
custNo  visitTime          FirstVisit

1234    2013-01-31 20:15  
1234    2013-01-31 22:30
1234    2013-02-15 02:30
1234    2013-02-15 06:30
1234    2013-02-15 11:30
1234    2013-02-15 21:30
```

I am trying to do some `Daily analysis` using `custNo`. As you can see above the customer number repeats itself. One day is `2013-01-31 1:00am` to `2013-02-01 00:59am`. I am trying to come up with a query for `FirstVistTime`. So for`31st Jan`, it should be `2013-01-31 20:15` and for `15th Feb` it should be `2013-02-15 02:30`.

So far I came up with this query:

```
select custNo, visitTime, FirstVisit=(select MIN(c.visitTime) FROM customer c  where
(c.custNo=ct.custNo and c.visitTime >= '01/01/2013 01:00' and c.visitTime < '03/01/2013 
01:00') 
from customer ct 
where visitTime >= '01/01/2013 01:00' 
    and visitTime < '03/01/2013 01:00'
```

The problem with this is - if the `custNo` repeats it takes all the rows into account and calculates the minimum date, which in the above case would be  `2013-01-31 20:15`. I tried to use `min(visitTime)over(partition by custNo,visitTime)`. Well it is a `subquery` that returns two values.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
select custNo, min(visitTime) from customer 
group by custNo, CAST(visitTime AS date)
order by custNo
```

or:

```
select t1.custNo, t1.visitTime, t2.minVal 
from customer t1 left join 
(
  select custno, min(visitTime) as minVal  from customer 
  group by custno, CAST(visitTime AS date)      
) t2 on t1.custNo = t2.custNo and CAST(t2.minVal as date) = CAST(t1.visitTime as date)
order by t1.custNo
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually, you should just be able to group by customer and date, and select the minimum visit time for each customer and date:

```
SELECT custNo, MIN(visitTime)
FROM customer c
GROUP BY custNo, CONVERT(DATE, visitTime, 112)
ORDER BY custNo, MIN(visitTime)
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you're looking for?

```
SELECT custno, min(visit)
FROM visitors
GROUP BY custno, CONVERT(DATE, VISIT)
ORDER BY custno, min(visit)
```

Here is a [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/25e11/30)